# How to issue same color scale to points and bars in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe and would like issue the same color to points and bars using ggplot. Unfortunately, ggplot picks it's own gradient scale even though the same continuous variable is picked for both points and bars.

How can I force ggplot to use the same color scale for both? See example below:

```
data <- structure(list(ind = structure(c(5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Indicator 5", 
                                                                         "Indicator 4", "Indicator 3", "Indicator 2", "Indicator 1"), class = "factor"), 
                       value = c(2L, 26L, 29L, 39L, 40L), Target = c(20L, 30L, 30L, 
                                                                     45L, 60L), LastYr = c(90L, 80L, 95L, 80L, 50L), Perc.time = c(92.539356605065, 
                                                                                                                                   92.539356605065, 92.539356605065, 92.539356605065, 92.539356605065
                                                                     ), Perc = c(10, 86.6666666666667, 96.6666666666667, 86.6666666666667, 
                                                                                 66.6666666666667), Behind = c(-10, -5.87268993839835, 0, 
                                                                                                               -5.87268993839835, -10), tex = c("Need 17 more", "Need 2 more", 
                                                                                                                                                "OK!", "Need 3 more", "Need 16 more")), .Names = c("ind", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   "value", "Target", "LastYr", "Perc.time", "Perc", "Behind", "tex"
                                                                                                                                                ), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(ind))+ 
  geom_bar(aes(y=Perc,width=0.2,fill=Behind),stat = "identity") + 
  geom_point(aes(y=Perc,color=Behind),size=10) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "red",high="dark green", limits=c(LowLVL,0))
```

And the resulting plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to set the colour for your bar, so try this

```
ggplot(data, aes(ind))+ 
  geom_bar(aes(y=Perc,width=0.2,fill=Behind),stat = "identity") + 
  geom_point(aes(y=Perc,color=Behind),size=10) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "red",high="dark green") + scale_fill_gradient(low = "red",high="dark green")
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.